# How to sum across a row in KDB/Q

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a table rCom which has various columns. I would like to sum across each row..

for example:

> Date      TypeA  TypeB  TypeC  TypeD
>
> date1     40.5    23.1   45.1   65.2
>
> date2     23.3    32.2   56.1   30.1

How can I write a q query to add a fourth column 'Total' that sums across each row?

Answer (score 2):

why not just:

```
update Total: TypeA+TypeB+TypeC+TypeD from rCom
```

?

Comment: (replace with the appropriate select statement if rCom is not update-able of course)

Answer (score 2):

Sum will work just fine:

```
q)flip`a`b`c!3 3#til 9
a b c
-----
0 3 6
1 4 7
2 5 8
q)update d:sum(a;b;c) from flip`a`b`c!3 3#til 9
a b c d
--------
0 3 6 9
1 4 7 12
2 5 8 15
```

Sum has map reduce which will be better for a huge table.

Answer (score 1):

One quick point regarding summing across rows. You should be careful about nulls in 1 column resulting in a null result for the sum. Borrowing @WooiKent Lee's example.

We put a null into the first position of the a column. Notice how our sum now becomes null

```
q)wn:.[flip`a`b`c!3 3#til 9;(0;`a);first 0#] //with null
q)update d:sum (a;b;c) from wn
a b c d
--------
  3 6
1 4 7 12
2 5 8 15
```

This is a direct effect of the way nulls in `q` are treated. If you sum across a simple list, the nulls are ignored

```
q)sum 1 2 3 0N
6
```

However, a sum across a general list will not display this behavior

```
q)sum (),/:1 2 3 0N
,0N
```

So, for your table situation, you might want to fill in with a zero beforehand

```
q)update d:sum 0^(a;b;c) from wn
a b c d
--------
  3 6 9
1 4 7 12
2 5 8 15
```

Or alternatively, make it s.t. you are actually summing across simple lists rather than general lists.

```
q)update d:sum each flip (a;b;c) from wn
a b c d
--------
  3 6 9
1 4 7 12
2 5 8 15
```

For a more complete reference on null treatment please see [the reference website](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/4_Operators/#410-operations-on-infinities-and-nulls)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
select Answer:{[x;y;z;a] x+y+z+a }'[TypeA;TypeB;TypeC;TypeD] from 
([] dt:2014.01.01 2014.01.02 2014.01.03; TypeA:4 5 6; TypeB:1 2 3; TypeC:8 9 10; TypeD:3 4 5)
```

Comment: if you just add the columns, select colA+colB etc, it will sum across